# Less than operator not working properly in a PHP while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, comparison-operators

I'm trying to do some calculations on getting the total points used in a requested amount of money based on the amount per points.

Kindly refer to below code:

```
<?php
$amount_perpoints = bcdiv(622.9106666666667,1,2); // AMOUNT OF MONEY PER POINTS
$request_amount = 3114.55; //REQUESTED AMOUNT OF POINTS

$points = 0; // THIS WILL CONTAIN THE TOTAL POINTS
$total_amount = 0; // THIS WILL INCREMENT ACCORDING TO THE PRODUCT OF THE CURRENT POINT AND AMOUNT PER POINTS

while($total_amount < $request_amount){ 
    $points = $points+0.50; //POINTS INCREMENTING BY 0.5
    $total_amount = $points * $amount_perpoints;
}

echo $points;

?>
```

Output: `5.50`

Above scenario outputs `5.50` but I believe it should only be `5.00`. At `5.00` points of the iteration, `$total_amount` and `$request_amount` has already same value of `3114.55`. Why does the while loop still satisfies even the two values of the comparing variables are not less than BUT EQUAL?

Comment: Have you tried while($total_amount <= $request_amount){ which is the equivalence of saying less than or equal to

Comment: I tried it @jeff same result 5.5

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that while loop will just run another iteration. OP you could try without loop with this `$points = $request_amount / $amount_perpoints`.

Answer (score 1):

Your are comparing float numbers. Try to use

```
while (bccomp($total_amount, $request_amount) === -1) {
```

Comment: OP test number results to `622.91` which doesn't lead to a repeating errror. The while loop is the problem. OP needs a condition after the iteration, aka *until* loop.

Comment: but this loop print `5` as result :/ which is correct (?)

Comment: You might be on to something. I hope OP will weigh in though as all she gave us was a sample value. But the comparison on floating point makes sense. So until otherwise, upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think @jeff is right:

```
 $amount_perpoints = bcdiv(622.9106666666667,1,2); // AMOUNT OF MONEY PER POINTS
    $request_amount = 3114.55; //REQUESTED AMOUNT OF POINTS

    $points = 0; // THIS WILL CONTAIN THE TOTAL POINTS
    $total_amount = 0; // THIS WILL INCREMENT ACCORDING TO THE PRODUCT OF THE CURRENT POINT AND AMOUNT PER POINTS

    while($total_amount <= $request_amount){ 
        $points = $points+0.50; //POINTS INCREMENTING BY 0.5
        $total_amount = $points * $amount_perpoints;
    }

    echo $points;
```

Since you count untill it reach the desired point it sould be less OR equal. It give the output of : 5.5

Comment: Tried that still 5.5.

Comment: can you provide any MATH of your Calculations?

Comment: No math. Just copied pasted OP code and put in `<=`. 5.5 was result on `$points`.

Comment: Then there is now any prof that it should be a `5.0`, unless you can prof that with you calcs.

Comment: Ok, i'd say OP wants the "floor" but if OP isn't saying it, who knows? The while loop is the problem. It's difficult to know what the expected results are except from what the OP states.

Comment: yep, it is true

Comment: Is an XY problem indeed!

Comment: i do not see any problem, it is just a basic math functions, and the way how you interpret them.

Comment: Trust me SergheiLeonenco i ran thru thru the calculations. But if OP wants points awarded on arbitrary amounts, then the "floor" context has to be on the measure of the point increment. And what happens is the while loop doesnt do it justice at the end. A "division" needs to take place.

Comment: then use round funtion to get rid off your decimals. `round ( float $val [, int $precision = 0 [, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP ]] ) : float` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Like that, *exactly*. .... In that neighborhood of a solution. A loop will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$amount_perpoints = bcdiv(622.9106666666667,1,2); // AMOUNT OF MONEY PER POINTS
$request_amount = 3114.55; //REQUESTED AMOUNT OF POINTS

$points = 0; // THIS WILL CONTAIN THE TOTAL POINTS
$new_points=0;
$total_amount = 0; // THIS WILL INCREMENT ACCORDING TO THE PRODUCT OF THE CURRENT POINT AND AMOUNT PER POINTS

while($total_amount < $request_amount){
    $points=$new_points;
    $new_points = $new_points+0.50; //POINTS INCREMENTING BY 0.5
    $total_amount = $new_points * $amount_perpoints;
}

echo $points;

?>
```

Comment: you need to hold $points when $total_amount < $request_amount
but in last loop $total_amount >= $request_amount
so you need to hold value before this increment, so I am holding value in current point value in $new_points and old point of privious loop run in $point

Answer (score 0):

Errors occur when calculating with fractional fractions as a float. Float cannot represent certain decimal numbers exactly. Use only the BC Math functions  for such calculations. You don't need a loop either.

```
$amount_perpoints = "622.91"; // AMOUNT OF MONEY PER POINTS
$request_amount = "3114.55"; //REQUESTED AMOUNT OF POINTS for result 5.0
//$request_amount = "3426.005"; //REQUESTED AMOUNT OF POINTS for result 5.5

$point_step = "0.50";

//calculation
$points = bcdiv($request_amount,$point_step,2);
$points = bcdiv($points,$amount_perpoints,0);
$points = bcmul($points,$point_step,1);

//output
var_dump($points);  //string(3) "5.0"
```